# How to access resources by name in c#

Tags: c#, file, resources

I have a resource file with map markers such as the following:
[image]

Now in my renderer, I would like to grab a given marker by its name in order to render it on the map.
(not working) Example:

```
foreach (PointTypes.PointType type in pointTypes)
{
    string pointTypeName = type.GetName();
    // how to do the following?
    Bitmap selectedIcon = Resources.Map_Marker.GetItemByName("Marker_"+pointTypeName)
    // Render the obtained Marker on the map
}
```

What would be the apropriate way?

Comment: @CoderCharmander Reading files itself is not the issue. I thought, I do it properly for once and use the resource designer.

Comment: The answers say how to get a stream from a resource file. You can create an `Image` from the stream.